# Error: double-linked list on Raspberry PI3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i have a problem in raspberry pi3 , when i run grgsm tool i have this error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ grgsm_scanner
linux; GNU C++ version 6.2.0 20161010; Boost_106100; UHD_003.009.005-0-unknown


*** Error in `/usr/bin/python2': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00bf9fe0 ***
Aborted
```

can anyone help me please ?
thanks,

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Comment: is working in ubuntu mate

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message running gnuradio on the rpi3 (raspbian), and I found this question, so for posterity, I was able to get it working by installing [Ubuntu MATE for Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) on my rpi3, and running `sudo apt install gnuradio` and `sudo apt install grgsm_scanner`.  `grgsm_scanner` (and gnuradio in general) launches fine now.

Answer (score -1):

the python interpreter is written in C and this error is caused by `glibc` see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=907649 and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3304/

normally this due to memory leaks in the code, however in case of gnuradio that is a really complex code it is possible that during the installation process some modules were missed. in 2013 this caused a similar error ( `osmoSDR` not installed )